# How safe is using an std::atomic<int> index to asynchronously parallelize operation on large array

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a parallelized routine to perform a series of calculations on each object in a large array of pointers where the calculations require each thread to be able to read all the other objects but will only ever write to exactly one object. I set it up similar to the below

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

void threadFunction(Object** objects, int n);

std::atomic<int> idx;
int nobjects = 10000;

int main() {
  int nthreads = 4;
  Object** objects = new Object*[nobjects];

  idx = 0;
  std::thread threads[nthreads];
  for (int ii = 0; ii < nthreads; ii ++) {
    threads[ii] = std::thread(threadFunction, objects, ii);
  }

  while (idx < nobjects - 1) {}    // Wait until all the calculations have been done

  for (int ii = 0; ii < nthreads; ii ++) {
    threads[ii].join();
  }
}

void threadFunction(Object** objects, int n) {
  Object* current = NULL;
  while (idx < nobjects - 1) {
    current = objects[idx++];
    // do calculation
  }
}
```

Where `Object` is a custom class, but could be substituted for a primitive for these purposes. My question is how 'safe' is doing it this way? I understand that `atomic` types are protected from partial write but how certain can I be that this will work every time even for large arrays?

This may be too specific but I would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

Comment: what about order of writes and reads? You will get different result depending on the order of reads and writes unless you make a copy in which case there is no issue anymore

Comment: This isn't safe at all. Other thread may kick in between the test of while loop and the array access. `while` can't guarantee that `idx` is in range.

Comment: if thread A comes first then B will use the updated value, if B comes first A will read the value updated by A

Comment: This is not safe as there is a race condition between the threads' `while` loop condition (`idx < nobjects - 1`) and the `idx++` in the loop body.

Comment: You have a race between `idx < nobjects - 1` and `objects[idx++]`. The condition may no longer be true by the time you get an index, and you risk going over the bounds of your array.

Comment: The size of the array does not matter. An `atomic` variable will only ever be modified by one thread of execution at a time and the result will be visible to all other threads as either updated or not updated. That's the whole *point* of atomics (the details get muddy when you stray outside sequential consistency - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order , but then you are *required* to *know what you are doing*). You can still have race conditions though, with *other* variables or usages of your `atomic` variable. But the variable itself is safe.

Comment: This is going to be a very bad for cache efficiency.  You should give each thread a slice of the array to work on and then you don't need any synchronization.  If you have 4 threads and 1000 objects then thread 1 works on index 0-249, 2 works on 250-499, 3 works on 500-749, and 4 works on 750, 999 and you are guaranteed to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you have a race condition between checking your loop condition and using the value of `idx`.  This may cause you to read past the end of the array.  Your thread function just needs a slight tweak:

```
void threadFunction(Object** objects, int n) {
  Object* current = NULL;
  while (true) {
    int next = idx++;
    if (next < nobjects - 1) {
      current = objects[next];
      // do calculation
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

In general, proving that a lock-free algorithm is correct is hard and can only be done by a careful inspection of the code.  The size of the array has no bearing on this algorithm's correctness in any case.

**Using the standard library**

Although this wasn't specifically asked, it's probably worth pointing out that this can all be done through the standard library (which avoids the tricky safety questions and handles issues like partitioning).  Something like the following:

```
void DoCalculations(Object& obj)
{
  // details...
}

// later...

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> objects = CreateObjects();
std::for_each(
  std::execution::par,
  objects.begin(),
  objects.end(),
  [] (std::unique_ptr<Object> const& p) { DoCalculations(*p); });
```

Comment: FWIW, you could use a for loop like `for(int index = idx++; index < nobjects - 1; index = idx++) { current = objects[index];
      // do calculation}`